# How to change the .htaccess file in codeigniter for reading wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a website which is designed using codeigniter framework.For crating blog page I used wordpress by referring this link [click here](http://rashmit.codeint.com/integrating-wordpress-inside-codeigniter-seamlessly/)

using this I have created a page. but for comments and all its going to 
the below url

```
http://localhost/mywebsite/blog/index.php/2016/04/29/my-new-blog/#respond
```

because of the .htacces restriction its showing 404 error page

below is my .htaccess code which I have tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|info\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(blog)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

but still it's not working

Comment: In this link `http://localhost/mywebsite/blog/index.php/2016/04/29/my-new-blog/#respond` is `blog` subdirectory? I understood it is a controller, so it should be after `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Installed wordpress for your Blog alone. Just fallow the steps

1)create a page using wordpress dashboard called as blog

```
  By page->new->blog->publish
```

2)Just make it as a front page

```
 By settings->Front page displays->Posts page or front page->blog
```

3)just copy that URL of page and you can use it where you want it in codeigniter framework to open the blog

4)If you have any problem in 404 again then you can check with .htaccess or permalink

```
Go to settings-> permalink-> set it as default ->Reload or refresh
Then again now Go to settings-> permalink->postname
Your .htaccess will get update with the permalink.
```

Comment: i have stored the wordpress file inside wp folder. now its working but the link shoes http://localhost/mywebsite/wp/blog. I dont want to show wp.

Comment: Are you want show up another link instead of this link? if yes goto->pages->blog->title you can see Permalink: http://localhost/mywebsite/blog you can change here.

Comment: hi i have selected plain.but if you go to some other blog its showing wp?

Comment: ok go to settings->permalink->custom structure-> you can define your url and let me when it worked out from above is steps 4?